# SMO copy table structure but not defaults

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

I am trying to copy tables (structure not data) using the Transfer object. I do not want to copy the default values in the columns as they have stored procedures I dont want to reference in them and hence crashes the transfer.

Can anyone tell me how to copy tables and not their default constraints?

```
        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);
        transfer.CopyAllObjects = false;
        transfer.CopyData = false;
        transfer.CopyAllTables = false;
        transfer.DestinationDatabase = destinationDatabase.Name;
        transfer.DestinationServer = sourceServer.Name;

        foreach (Table sourceTable in sourceDatabase.Tables)
        {
            transfer.ObjectList.Add(sourceTable);
        }

        transfer.TransferData();
```

Thanks

Comment: From `Sql` end you can use this `select * into newtable from existingtable where 1=0`

Answer (score 0):

This code will copy only the table definitions with it primary keys, unyque keys and indexes, but without any relationships between tables.

```
Transfer transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);   

transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = sourceServer.DestinationLoginSecure;
transfer.DestinationLogin = sourceServer.ConnectionContext.Login;
transfer.DestinationPassword = sourceServer.ConnectionContext.Password;

transfer.DestinationDatabase = destinationDatabase.Name;
transfer.DestinationServer = sourceServer.Name;

transfer.CopyAllObjects = false;
transfer.CopyAllTables = false;
transfer.CopySchema = true;
transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;

transfer.Options.WithDependencies = false;
transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;
transfer.Options.DriAll = false;
transfer.Options.DriDefaults = false;
transfer.Options.DriIndexes = true;
transfer.Options.DriPrimaryKey = true;
transfer.Options.DriUniqueKeys = true;
transfer.Options.DriForeignKeys = false;
transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;

foreach (Table sourceTable in sourceDatabase.Tables)
{
    transfer.ObjectList.Add(sourceTable);
}

transfer.TransferData();
```